# writeVideo error in MatLAB

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, frame, video-processing

I have images that I'm overlaying some tracks onto and then turning into a movie, but I'm getting this error (about the lines at the very end of the code I have).

```
??? Undefined function or method 'writeVideo' for
input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

The error is coming at the very last line of this piece of code:

```
% add this frame to movie file
    %mov = addframe(mov,gcf);
    renderer = get(hnd,'renderer');
    if strcmp(renderer,'painters')
        renderer = 'opengl';
    end
    set(hnd, 'Units', 'pixels');
    pixelsperinch = get(0,'screenpixelsperInch');

    frame = hardcopy(hnd, ['-d' renderer], ['-r' num2str(round(pixelsperinch))]);
    writeVideo('mov',frame); %error appears here
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the `VideoWriter` class? Where have you created the video object with the constructor? The first input to `writeVideo` needs to be the object, not a file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on Acoustic77's comment, it looks like you have your VideoWriter object as mov, but you're passing the string 'mov' instead of the object mov to writeVideo.

```
% demo using random data and surface plot

mov = VideoWriter('demo.avi');
mov.open;

figure;
for x = 1:10
    data = rand(25,25);
    surf(data);

    renderer = get(gcf,'renderer');
    if strcmp(renderer,'painters')
        renderer = 'opengl';
    end
    frame = hardcopy(gcf, ['-d' renderer], ['-r' num2str(round(300))]);

    writeVideo(mov, frame);

end

mov.close;
mov.delete;
```